# Installing ext-libevent, ext-libev, ext-event for php

Tags: centos, centos6, php

I installed [reactphp](https://github.com/reactphp/react) on my LAMP environment (CentOS 6.4). After the installation was successful, I got this message:

```
react/react suggests installing ext-libevent (Allows for use of a more performant event-loop implementation.)

react/react suggests installing ext-libev (Allows for use of a more performant event-loop implementation.)

react/react suggests installing ext-event (Allows for use of a more performant event-loop implementation.)
```

How can I install ext-libevent, ext-libev and ext-event? Thanks!

Comment: The important question is how did you install PHP?

Comment: @MichaelHampton actually my question was not that clear. I installed php with yum, but the libevent, libev dependencies were not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some digging around, it looks like this is a PECL package. There are some RPMs available but doesn't look like they're in any of the major third-party repos that are tested as safe to install and not cause dependency problems.

So, first step on CentOS would be setup PECL;

```
yum groupinstall "development tools"
yum install pecl-event php-devel libevent-devel
pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
```

Next, you would normally just try to install it (pecl install libevent), however, it is going to complain that your PHP is too old and to use the direct path.

```
pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/libevent-0.1.0
```

Finally, we have to tell PHP that this was installed. On 64bit CentOS, the extensions' shared libraries default to /usr/lib64/php/modules; you can use the following command to verify that.

```
php --info | grep extension_dir
```

Make sure the "so" file exists (looking for libevent.so)

```
ls -lah /usr/lib64/php/modules
```

If it is there, now you can safely create the appropriate configuration file for it:

```
touch /etc/php.d/libevent.ini
vim /etc/php.d/libevent.ini
```

> ```
> ; Enable libevent PECL extension
> extension=libevent.so
> ```

Be warned that you will need to be vigilent when you do updates to your system as some circumstances can break the PHP extensions. Just do a pecl uninstall and pecl install to resolve it. Restart your webserver to apply the new PHP configuration and give it a spin!